# Array reduction with OpenMP leads to "user defined reduction not found for"

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I'm doing a scholar work and I have to obtain the histogram from a IMAGE.

All is going well, but when I tried to make the code parallel with the OpenMP, the compiler returns me this error: `user defined reduction not found for 'histog'`

The code that I used is this:

```
void HistogramaParaleloRed(int *histog)
{

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
        {
            histog[i] = 0;
        }

        #pragma omp for reduction(+ : histog)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                histog[IMAGEN[i][j]]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the call to the function in Main is: `HistogramaParaleloRed(histog_pal_red);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error

```
user defined reduction not found for
```

can happen because either the code was compiled with a compiler that does not support the [OpenMP 4.5](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) array reduction feature (or that compiler is misconfigured) or because your are trying the reduce a *naked* pointer (**like it is the case of your example**). In the latter, the compiler cannot *tell* how many elements are to be reduce.

So either you use a compiler that supports `OpenMP 5.0` and take advantage of *array sections* feature as follows:

```
void HistogramaParaleloRed(int *histog)
{

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
        {
            histog[i] = 0;
        }

        #pragma omp for reduction(+ : histog[:N])
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                histog[IMAGEN[i][j]]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively, implement the reduction yourself.

**Implement the Reduction manually**

One approach is to create a shared structure among threads (*i.e.,* *thread_histog*), then each thread updates its position, and afterward, threads reduce the values of the shared structure into the original *histog* array.

```
void HistogramaParaleloRed(int *histog, int number_threads)
{
    int thread_histog[number_threads][NG] = {{0}};
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                thread_histog[thread_id][IMAGEN[i][j]]++;

       #pragma omp for no_wait
       for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < number_threads; j++)
              histog[i] += thread_histog[j][i]
    }
}
```

Another approach is to create an array of locks, one for each element of the `histog` array. Whenever a thread updates a given `histog` position, first acquires the lock corresponded to that position so that no other thread will be updating concurrently the same array position.

```
void HistogramaParaleloRed(int *histog)
{
    omp_lock_t locks[NG];
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       #pragma omp for
       for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
            omp_init_lock(&locks[i]);

        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
              int pos = IMAGEN[i][j]
              omp_set_lock(&locks[pos]);
              thread_histog[thread_id][pos]++; 
              omp_unset_lock(&locks[pos]);
          }

       #pragma omp for no_wait
       for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
            omp_destroy_lock(&locks[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the answer worked well!
And you are right, I reinstall my compilator and that was the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The error is attempting to directly reduce the argument pointer `int *histog`. You must instead reduce a local *array*, and copy over the reduced results to `histog`.

```
void HistogramaParaleloRed(int *histog)
{
    int localHistog[NG];

    /*
     * your code as before, replacing histog with localHistog
     */

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
        {
            localHistog[i] = 0;
        }

        #pragma omp for reduction(+ : localHistog)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                localHistog[IMAGEN[i][j]]++;
            }
        }

        /* 
         * copy localHistog into output histog
         */

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++)
        {
            histog[i] = localHistog[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for point my mistake out, you can use also the "array sections feature" from OpenMP 5.0 and avoid having to reduce manually