# OpenMP in C array reduction / parallelize the code

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a problem with my code, it should print number of appearances of a certain number.

I want parallelize this code with OpenMP, and I tried to use reduction for arrays but it's obviously didn't working as I wanted.

The error is: "segmentation fault". Should some variables be private? or it's the problem with the way I'm trying to use the reduction?

I think each thread should count some part of array, and then merge it somehow.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+: reasult[:i])
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {   
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
         if ( numbers[j] == i){
            result[i]++;
         }
      }
  }
```

Where `N` is big number telling how many numbers I have. Numbers is array of all numbers and result array with sum of each number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have a typo on the name

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+: reasult[:i])
```

should actually be "result" not "reasult"

Nonetheless, why are you *section* the array with `result[:i]`? Based on your code, it seems that you wanted to reduce the entire array, namely:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+: result)
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)   
      for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
         if ( numbers[j] == i)
            result[i]++;
```

When one's compiler does not support the [OpenMP 4.5](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) array reduction feature one can alternatively explicitly implement the reduction ([check this SO thread to see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852864/array-reduction-with-openmp-leads-to-user-defined-reduction-not-found-for/)).

As pointed out by @[Hristo Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev) in the comments:

> Provided that M * sizeof(result[0]) / #threads is a multiple of the
> cache line size, and even if it isn't when the value of M is large
> enough, there is absolutely no need to involve reduction in the
> process. Unless the program is running on a NUMA system, that is.

Assuming that the aforementioned conditions are met, and if you analyze carefully the outermost loop iterations (*i.e.*, variable `i`) are assigned to the threads, and since the variable  `i` is used to access the `result` array, each thread will be updating a different position of the `result` array. Therefore, you can simplified your code to:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)   
   for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if ( numbers[j] == i)
         result[i]++;
```

Comment: Provided that `M * sizeof(result[0]) / #threads` is a multiple of the cache line size, and even if it isn't when the value of `M` is large enough, there is absolutely no need to involve reduction in the process. Unless the program is running on a NUMA system, that is.