# openmp collapse with inner loop reduction

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, simd

I'm trying to vectorise a nested loop with #pragma omp simd, but the inner loop has a reduction in it. Is there any way to do this?

```
  #pragma omp simd collapse(2) reduction(+:total[i])
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++){

      float distance = sqrt(
      (x[i][0]-x[j][0]) * (x[i][0]-x[j][0]) +
      (x[i][1]-x[j][1]) * (x[i][1]-x[j][1]) +
      (x[i][2]-x[j][2]) * (x[i][2]-x[j][2])
      );

      total[i] += distance; 
    }
  }
```

at the moment, it just gives this error when compiling:

```
error: identifier "i" is undefined
#pragma omp simd collapse(2) reduction(+:total[i])
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass the variable 'i' to `+:total[i]` either you specify the array subsection to be reduced or just do `+:total`. Bear in mind, however, that you need a compiler that supports [OpenMP 4.5](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) array reduction feature.

```
  #pragma omp simd collapse(2) reduction(+:total)
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++){

      float distance = sqrt(
      (x[i][0]-x[j][0]) * (x[i][0]-x[j][0]) +
      (x[i][1]-x[j][1]) * (x[i][1]-x[j][1]) +
      (x[i][2]-x[j][2]) * (x[i][2]-x[j][2])
      );

      total[i] += distance; 
    }
  }
```

When one's compiler does not support the [OpenMP 4.5](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) array reduction feature one can alternatively explicitly implement the reduction ([check this SO thread to see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852864/array-reduction-with-openmp-leads-to-user-defined-reduction-not-found-for/)).